# How to add "shopt -s compat31" command in all shell scripts?

Tags: linux, bash

Bash package is updated from *bash-3.2-32* to *bash-4.1.2-15.el6_5.1.x86_64*. After upgrade, the regex matching conditional operator =~ can regex  matching to stop working. How to add

```
shopt -s compat31
```

command in all shell scripts? I don't want to add this command in all scripts one by one.

I have added above command into .bashrc but compatibility is not refleted on shell scripts.
Command result:

```
compat31 is off in script.
[root@localhost log]# sh abc.sh
compat31        off

Compat31 is  on at command prompt screen.
[root@localhost log]# shopt |grep compat31
compat31        on
[root@localhost log]#
```

Comment: You *might* be able to change `/bin/bash` into a symlink to a script which runs `shopt -s compat31` and then invokes `bash`. I have no idea how well this will work or what it may break in the process.

Comment: According to you, we first create symlink from /bin/bash to script. example: ln -s /bin/bash abc.sh . abc.sh run shopt command. Is it correct?

Comment: You are going to have to edit the scripts in some way; shell options are not propagated to child shells, such as when running the script from a shell with the option set.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- The regex operator [changed in 3.2alpha](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges#conditional_expressions_and_test_command), but I can't see a reference to any changes after that. In other words, there's no mention of changes between the versions you mention.
- The change in the `=~` behaviour in 3.2alpha is simply to treat quoted right-hand strings as literal string matches rather than regular expressions. You literally just have to remove any quotes from it to make your old code work with 3.2alpha.
- The regex operator is still very much working, and very likely better than in 3.1.
- Unless you absolutely cannot change the code it's probably better to be compatible with the current version. Too much catering to old code makes it even harder to migrate later, and more likely to have subtle bugs.

Comment: By default RHEL6.5 machine is use bash-4.1.2-15.el6_5.1.x86_64 version. So ,how to handle compatibility as compat31?

Comment: Any solution for bash4.1.2 package to enable compat31?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to run the script with

```
bash -O compat31 oldscript.bash
```

rather than editing the script itself.

Comment: There are multiple scripts and internally call other scripts. So, how to handle the same for all scripts.